Optimized Lanczos method for finding eigenvalues of $A \otimes B$
Recently my supervisor told me about an efficient way to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $A \otimes B$ with $a_{1} \times a_{2}$ as dimensions of $A$ and $b_{1} \times b_{2}$ is of $B$. Instead of creating this matrix directly (which occupies large amount of RAM because of large dimension $(a_{1}\times b_{1}, a_{2}\times b_{2})$ ) and after that compute eigenvalues, he proposed an optimized Lanczos method that uses a vector $v_{1}$ with dimension $b_{2}\times a_{1}$ so that in each step, new vector defined by:
$$
w_{i+1} = A  v_{i}  B^T. 
$$
It will be used in the Lanczos algorithm.
I'll be grateful if someone can introduce any references or answer here why this method works and talk a little about the mathematical formula behind this method.

By the way, the correct identity is $(A\otimes B)\operatorname{vec}(V) = \operatorname{vec}(BXA^T)$, where $T$ stands for a transpose (without conjugation).

You could also ask your supervisor :-)

@WolfgangBangerth its a task that I have to solve it :)

Is it homework?

The key note is to rewrite Kronecker's product as a matrix multiplication. At first, if we denote bases of $A$ as ${|a_{i}\rangle}$ and $B$ as ${|b_{i}\rangle}$ (apology if I used unconventional bra&ket notation), we can replace an equivalent equation instead of $A\otimes B |v\rangle$. Here is necessary steps:

first, by writing $|v\rangle$ in mentioned bases:
$$
|v\rangle = \sum_{i,j} v_{ij} |a_{i}\rangle\otimes|b_{j}\rangle
$$
we can reshape vector $|v\rangle$ to a matrix form ($V$) by simply map second basis ($|b\rangle$) to its dual space:
$$
|v\rangle \to \sum_{i,j} v_{ij} |a_{i}\rangle \otimes \langle b_{j}| = V
$$
the product $A\otimes B |v\rangle$ can brought to matrix multiplication form:
$$
A\otimes B |v\rangle = \sum_{i,j} v_{ij} (A|i\rangle) \otimes (B|j\rangle) \to
\sum_{i,j} v_{ij} (A|i\rangle) \otimes (\langle j|B^T)
$$
since dual vector of $B|j\rangle$ is $(B|j\rangle)^T$ or $\langle j|B^T$. Now it is easy to show that above equation equals to:
$$
= \sum_{i,j,m,n} v_{ij}(A_{m,i}|m\rangle (\langle n|B_{nj})
$$
or in matrix form:
$$
= A V B^T.
$$
Although this replacement of tensor product by matrix multiplication reduced size of matrices (and no out of memory error) but increase CPU usage because of matrix product.



There isn't much complicated behind this idea; it's just that since Lanczos is a black-box method you can use any method of your choice to compute the products $v\mapsto (A\otimes B)v$ needed in the algorithm, and this is a particularly efficient way to do it. All the theory is the same.

Do you really need to do this? Eigenvalues and a basis of eigenvectors of $A\otimes B$ are obtained easily from those of $A$ and $B$: take $\lambda_i\mu_j$ and $v_i\otimes w_j$, where $\lambda_i,v_i$ are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and $\mu_j,w_j$ of $B$.



Thanks for your answer! but how about generalized version of Kronecker's product like $\sum_{i} A_{i} \otimes B_{i}$? It seems to me that product of eigenvalues doesn't work in here

You are right, the trick doesn't work for a sum of Kronecker products. In that case the Lanczos approach makes sense.
